# Get an argument's value in a CodeActivity (Windows Workflow Foundation)

Tags: c#, workflow

Considering a Windows Workflow Foundation code activity such as this:

```cs
public sealed class MyActivity : CodeActivity
{
    public InArgument<string> SomeValue { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Is there any difference between

```cs
var x = context.GetValue(SomeValue);
```

and

```cs
var x = SomeValue.Get(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

They will return exactly the same value

string x = context.GetValue(SomeValue);

subsequently it can be written as string x = SomeValue.Get(context);